# how to download multiple webpages that use a 'next' button

Tags: java, html

I am trying to download the latest HTML code from this website, until recently the URL displayed all the information I needed. Recently the web designer changed the format so a portion of the data is displayed and the user must hit the 'next' button to display next portion of data.

The URL doesn't change though.

Anyone know how I can download all the information using JAVA??

Thanks. This is my current code:

```
[code]
URL url = null;
InputStream is = null;
BufferReader br;
String line;

try {

url = new URL("HTTP://...../..../...");
is = url.openStream();
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

while ( (line = br.readLine() ) != null)
   System.out.println(line);

} catch(IOException e) {


}

....

[/code]
```

Comment: Use [Selenium Webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) for automation

Comment: I got the Selenium to work and it does work.

Is there a method though that doesn't actually pull the up the browser? Something more behind the scenes and more universal? web driver requires one to choose a browser and have it installed.

Comment: Go with HTMLUnit driver a headless driver